# Oracle e business suite - UI label to database field mapping?

Tags: database, oracle, rdbms, oracle-apps

I am looking for some sort of a UI label:database field mapping
that tells me which UI field corresponds to which database column in the backend.

I am pretty sure that something like this must be existing in the Oracle e business suite... but my search has turned up nothing so far.

I would appreciate any help or pointers in this regard.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping isn't always 100% clearly defined, and can be more art than science.

From Forms-based E-Business Suite, place your cursor in the field in question, and navigate to Help > Diagnostics > Examine.  I combine this information with the e-Technical Resource Manuals from Oracle Support (http://etrm.oracle.com/pls/etrm/etrm_search.search).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. I appreciate it. I will try it out and report back.

Comment: Hey man.. thanks for pointing out the diagnostics. I am well on my way to solving my query. I t will take a few days. In case any one wants to know how I went about this... feel free to contact me and I will update the details.

Comment: hey Wolf, are you able to get that mapping UI field to data base column, same issue I am facing. If you are able to do this please help me for same. thanks